# Cmake exe file just run in my system in Sunshine project [terminate called after throwing an instance of std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error]

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I want to create one `.exe` file from the [Sunshine](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine) GitHub program, I'm new to Cmake and I build that program with its help

```
git clone https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine.git --recursive
cd sunshine && mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ..
mingw32-make
```

It builds and runs correctly and creates `.exe`, **but works only in my system**.
On other systems, it gets filesystem errors and shows the path of the system that I build it:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of
'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'   what():  filesystem
error: cannot copy file: No such file or directory
[E:/sunshine/assets/sunshine.conf] [E:/sunshine/assets/sunshine.conf]
```

**here is its `CMakeLists.txt` file:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Sunshine)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(third-party/Simple-Web-Server)

set(UPNPC_BUILD_SHARED OFF CACHE BOOL "no shared libraries")
set(UPNPC_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "Don't build tests for miniupnpc")
set(UPNPC_BUILD_SAMPLE OFF CACHE BOOL "Don't build samples for miniupnpc")
set(UPNPC_NO_INSTALL ON CACHE BOOL "Don't install any libraries build for miniupnpc")
add_subdirectory(third-party/miniupnp/miniupnpc)
include_directories(third-party/miniupnp)

if(WIN32)
    # Ugly hack to compile with #include <qos2.h>
    add_compile_definitions(
        QOS_FLOWID=UINT32
        PQOS_FLOWID=UINT32*
        QOS_NON_ADAPTIVE_FLOW=2)
endif()
add_subdirectory(third-party/moonlight-common-c/enet)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

list(APPEND SUNSHINE_COMPILE_OPTIONS -fPIC -Wall -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare)

if(WIN32)
    file(
        DOWNLOAD "https://github.com/TheElixZammuto/sunshine-prebuilt/releases/download/1.0.0/pre-compiled.zip" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pre-compiled.zip"
        TIMEOUT 60
        EXPECTED_HASH SHA256=5d59986bd7f619eaaf82b2dd56b5127b747c9cbe8db61e3b898ff6b485298ed6)

    file(ARCHIVE_EXTRACT
        INPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pre-compiled.zip"
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pre-compiled)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static")
    
    if(NOT DEFINED SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES)
        set(SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pre-compiled/windows")
    endif()

    add_compile_definitions(SUNSHINE_PLATFORM="windows")
    add_subdirectory(tools) #This is temporary, only tools for Windows are needed, for now

    list(APPEND SUNSHINE_DEFINITIONS APPS_JSON="apps_windows.json")

    include_directories(third-party/ViGEmClient/include)

    set(PLATFORM_TARGET_FILES
        sunshine/platform/windows/publish.cpp
        sunshine/platform/windows/misc.h
        sunshine/platform/windows/misc.cpp
        sunshine/platform/windows/input.cpp
        sunshine/platform/windows/display.h
        sunshine/platform/windows/display_base.cpp
        sunshine/platform/windows/display_vram.cpp
        sunshine/platform/windows/display_ram.cpp
        sunshine/platform/windows/audio.cpp
        third-party/ViGEmClient/src/ViGEmClient.cpp
        third-party/ViGEmClient/include/ViGEm/Client.h
        third-party/ViGEmClient/include/ViGEm/Common.h
        third-party/ViGEmClient/include/ViGEm/Util.h
        third-party/ViGEmClient/include/ViGEm/km/BusShared.h)

    set(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES
        libssl.a
        libcrypto.a)

    set(FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/include)
    set(FFMPEG_LIBRARIES
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libavcodec.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libavdevice.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libavfilter.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libavformat.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libavutil.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libpostproc.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libswresample.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libswscale.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libx264.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libx265.a
        ${SUNSHINE_PREPARED_BINARIES}/lib/libhdr10plus.a
        z lzma bcrypt libiconv.a)

    list(PREPEND PLATFORM_LIBRARIES
        libstdc++.a
        libwinpthread.a
        libssp.a
        ksuser
        wsock32
        ws2_32
        d3d11 dxgi D3DCompiler
        setupapi
        )

    set_source_files_properties(third-party/ViGEmClient/src/ViGEmClient.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "UNICODE=1;ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE_OBJECT_PARAMETER=650")
    set_source_files_properties(third-party/ViGEmClient/src/ViGEmClient.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-class-memaccess")
else()
    add_compile_definitions(SUNSHINE_PLATFORM="linux")
    list(APPEND SUNSHINE_DEFINITIONS APPS_JSON="apps_linux.json")

    find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
    find_package(FFmpeg REQUIRED)

    set(PLATFORM_TARGET_FILES
        sunshine/platform/linux/publish.cpp
        sunshine/platform/linux/vaapi.h
        sunshine/platform/linux/vaapi.cpp
        sunshine/platform/linux/misc.h
        sunshine/platform/linux/misc.cpp
        sunshine/platform/linux/display.cpp
        sunshine/platform/linux/audio.cpp
        sunshine/platform/linux/input.cpp
        third-party/glad/src/egl.c
        third-party/glad/src/gl.c
        third-party/glad/include/EGL/eglplatform.h
        third-party/glad/include/KHR/khrplatform.h
        third-party/glad/include/glad/gl.h
        third-party/glad/include/glad/egl.h)
        
    set(PLATFORM_LIBRARIES
        Xfixes
        Xtst
        xcb
        xcb-shm
        xcb-xfixes
        Xrandr
        ${X11_LIBRARIES}
        dl
        evdev
        pulse
        pulse-simple
        )
    
    set(PLATFORM_INCLUDE_DIRS
        ${X11_INCLUDE_DIR}
        /usr/include/libevdev-1.0
        third-party/glad/include)

    if(NOT DEFINED SUNSHINE_EXECUTABLE_PATH)
        set(SUNSHINE_EXECUTABLE_PATH "sunshine")
    endif()
    configure_file(gen-deb.in gen-deb @ONLY)
    configure_file(sunshine.service.in sunshine.service @ONLY)
endif()

add_subdirectory(third-party/cbs)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS log filesystem REQUIRED)

set(SUNSHINE_TARGET_FILES
    third-party/moonlight-common-c/reedsolomon/rs.c
    third-party/moonlight-common-c/reedsolomon/rs.h
    third-party/moonlight-common-c/src/Input.h
    third-party/moonlight-common-c/src/Rtsp.h
    third-party/moonlight-common-c/src/RtspParser.c
    third-party/moonlight-common-c/src/Video.h
    sunshine/upnp.cpp
    sunshine/upnp.h
    sunshine/cbs.cpp
    sunshine/utility.h
    sunshine/uuid.h
    sunshine/config.h
    sunshine/config.cpp
    sunshine/main.cpp
    sunshine/main.h
    sunshine/crypto.cpp
    sunshine/crypto.h
    sunshine/nvhttp.cpp
    sunshine/nvhttp.h
    sunshine/httpcommon.cpp
    sunshine/httpcommon.h
    sunshine/confighttp.cpp
    sunshine/confighttp.h
    sunshine/rtsp.cpp
    sunshine/rtsp.h
    sunshine/stream.cpp
    sunshine/stream.h
    sunshine/video.cpp
    sunshine/video.h
    sunshine/input.cpp
    sunshine/input.h
    sunshine/audio.cpp
    sunshine/audio.h
    sunshine/platform/common.h
    sunshine/process.cpp
    sunshine/process.h
    sunshine/network.cpp
    sunshine/network.h
    sunshine/move_by_copy.h
    sunshine/task_pool.h
    sunshine/thread_pool.h
    sunshine/thread_safe.h
    sunshine/sync.h
    sunshine/round_robin.h
    ${PLATFORM_TARGET_FILES})

set_source_files_properties(sunshine/upnp.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -Wno-pedantic)

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/cbs/include
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/moonlight-common-c/enet/include
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/moonlight-common-c/reedsolomon
  ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PLATFORM_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

string(TOUPPER "x${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" BUILD_TYPE)
if("${BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "XDEBUG")
    list(APPEND SUNSHINE_COMPILE_OPTIONS -O0 -pedantic -ggdb3)
    if(WIN32)
        set_source_files_properties(sunshine/nvhttp.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -O2)
    endif()
else()
    add_definitions(-DNDEBUG)
    list(APPEND SUNSHINE_COMPILE_OPTIONS -O3)
endif()

if(NOT SUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR)
    set(SUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets")
endif()

if(NOT SUNSHINE_CONFIG_DIR)
    set(SUNSHINE_CONFIG_DIR "${SUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR}")
endif()

if(NOT SUNSHINE_DEFAULT_DIR)
    set(SUNSHINE_DEFAULT_DIR "${SUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR}")
endif()

list(APPEND CBS_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES
    cbs)

list(APPEND SUNSHINE_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES
        libminiupnpc-static
        ${CBS_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES}
        ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
        stdc++fs
        enet
        opus
        ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
        ${PLATFORM_LIBRARIES})

list(APPEND SUNSHINE_DEFINITIONS SUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR="${SUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR}")
list(APPEND SUNSHINE_DEFINITIONS SUNSHINE_CONFIG_DIR="${SUNSHINE_CONFIG_DIR}")
list(APPEND SUNSHINE_DEFINITIONS SUNSHINE_DEFAULT_DIR="${SUNSHINE_DEFAULT_DIR}")
add_executable(sunshine ${SUNSHINE_TARGET_FILES})
target_link_libraries(sunshine ${SUNSHINE_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_definitions(sunshine PUBLIC ${SUNSHINE_DEFINITIONS})
set_target_properties(sunshine PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)

target_compile_options(sunshine PRIVATE ${SUNSHINE_COMPILE_OPTIONS})
```

I think in this file something makes this issue but I don't know.
This is its release file that works correctly and doesn't have my issue:

https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine/releases/download/v0.9.0/Sunshine-Windows.zip

**How can I create like this?**

Comment: Check the sunshine issue tracker and consider opening a new issue. [macOS support possibly? #127](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine/issues/127) and [Feature request: Add build support for other distros #50](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine/issues/50) sound relevant.

Comment: Thanks, @alterigel . I make one mistake in asking question. my exe in my windows run and works correctly but in other windows didn't work. but the [release of its repo](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine/releases/download/v0.9.0/Sunshine-Windows.zip)  doesn't have my issue.

Comment: Well, generally, this is why we have installers and usually don't just distribute executables directly.

Comment: thanks, @sweenish, in cmake project how do this? I don't know how to create an installer version

Comment: The problem description "it gets filesystem errors and show the path of the system that I build it" is very **vague**. Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact error message**, otherwise we simply cannot help you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev , I edit and add picture

Comment: @Tsyvarev , terminate called after throwing an instance of std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to put exact error message to the question post: among other things, the error message contains the exact path to the file `sunshine.conf`. And it seems that exact path is a problem: you configure the project with `SUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR` pointing to the source directory, and this directory is used by the project. You have two ways: 1. When configure the project, specify `SUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR` pointing to the directory with the configuration file on the **target** machine. 2. Follow the usage specified in the **documentation**: run "sunshine path/to/sunshine.conf".

Comment: I exactly didn't understand "run sunshine path/to/sunshine.conf". what does it mean and why the [release](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine/releases/download/v0.9.0/Sunshine-Windows.zip) that programmer puts didn't have my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed My problem by running CMake with one additional parameter.

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DSUNSHINE_ASSETS_DIR=assets ..
```

exe program needs to know assets and also after that assets folder should be near the exe file like a programmer release.